# Very slow curl request on testing existing remote file

Tags: php, curl

I met a problem today to which I can find no solution.

I have to make some statistic with data I get from a .csv file.

The path of those .csv files is dynamic and depends on 5 variables, so I have a loop to get all the urls that I need.

Finally I have around 540 urls to test. I am doing it with this function

```
public static function remoteFileExists( $url )
    {

        $curl = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec( $curl );

        $ret = false;
        if ( $result !== false ) {

            $statusCode = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

            if ( $statusCode == 200 || $statusCode == 302 ) {
                $ret = true;
            }
        }

        curl_close( $curl );

        return $ret;
    }
```

The function works perfectly but it currently takes 40-60sec to test all my urls.  This is taking way too much time.

Does anyone have a solution to reduce this time?

I already try with get_headers function, same amount of was time needed.

I also tried with this function :

```
public function remote_file_exists($url){
        return(bool)preg_match('~HTTP/1\.\d\s+200\s+OK~', @current(get_headers($url)));
    }
```

Same problem, it takes too much time.

Comment: Can you modify the code of the page called or is it a third party?

Comment: How often do you need to check them? I would store them in a database and use a cron-job to check them periodically and set the correct status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did the check in local, there is 2 differents site, but they are stored on the same server.
So i did the check with local call like '/var/...../..../files/.../file.csv

I reduce the loading time from 40-60 sec to 4sec.
At the moment it works, but i'm thinking, what is best solutio if one day i have this 2 website on separate server.

Answer (score -1):

Just set timeout whatever appropriate to you:

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);//will wait 30 sec
```

Comment: Won't that stop execution before it is complete? I mean... if that works, I'm gonna edit my php.ini file and set maximum timeout to 1 second to all of my pages!

Comment: call to curl_exec is blocking until server respond or timeout time exceeds

Comment: @Amarnasan why would you do that? `curl_setopt` affects only particular curl instance, no global settings will be changed

Comment: But if you set a limitation to the cURL functions to execute, you won't have any results if the scripts take longer to finish! Isn't worse than having to wait?

Comment: @Amarnasan well that is correct, there might be some bootstrap code above my example to get things done, like call to `set_time_limit` function  and so on. But it very depends on environment in which curl request made. So for example if php script called from command line, usually no additional steps need to be taken

Comment: Furhtermore in cgi environment you have little control on script execution on php side (there will be server connection timeout settings).